# Finding a value in a Dictionary with a key

Tags: c#-4.0

This particular code on an aspx page of mine is driving me nuts. I get an exception saying "The given key is not present in the Dictionary" on the 3rd line, saying that 'semester' is not a valid key in the dictionary 'records'. The thing is, the key I'm using has just come directly out of the dictionary! There must be something obvious I'm overlooking. Thanks.

```
    <% foreach (var semester in records.Keys) {%>
        <h3><a href="#"><%= semester.ToString() %></a></h3>
        <% foreach (var course in records[semester]) { %>
            <div>
            </div>
        <% } %>
    <% } %>
```

Comment: What type is `semester`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why that would happen.

Instead, you can loop through the key-value pairs:

```
<% foreach (var pair in records) {%>
    <h3><a href="#"><%= pair.Key %></a></h3>
    <% foreach (var course in pair.Value) { %>
        <div>
        </div>
    <% } %>
<% } %>
```

Comment: That did the trick! (I'll mark it as the answer when it lets me in a minute). Doesn't make sense to me though. Shouldn't the reference I'm passing in still work? In the immediate window I tried records.Contains(semester.Key) and that raised the same exception.

Comment: Calling `Contains` threw an exception?  That can't happen.